# Regex to match words which have vowels which are not in a discord emoji

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I'm working on making a discord bot that deletes every message that contains vowels (I know its weird, but its just for a joke between my friends and I). The way I'm checking if a message has a vowel is using regex, and I'm trying to refine my regex so it allows for emojis(their names may contain vowels).

What I need the regex to do is match any string with vowels in it, something like :

```js
"example" //should match
```

EXCEPT it must NOT match a string like this (this is the way my bot sees emojis), regardless if it has vowels. something like:

```js
"<:example:760518199699308544>" //shouldnt match
```

Matching any word with vowels in it is easy:

```js
/\w*[aeiou]\w*/gi
```

Or matching any emoji is easy:

```js
/<:\w*:\d{18}>/gi
```

But I've been messing around with positive and negative lookahead/lookbehind to try to merge these two for about an hour and can't seem to work it out. Please help if you know what I need to do here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a regex dialect which supports lookarounds, check that the word is not immediately preceded by `<:`

```
/(?<!<:)\b\w*[aeiou]\w*/gi
```

The trailing `\w*` is unnecessary here as such, but I left it in in case you want to match the whole word for some reason.

Comment: This hasn't been working for me... take a look at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTwPyg/1). It seems that the lookbehind isn't capturing the whole group after it or something. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: Try adding `\b` before `\w*`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this. If you wouldn't mind, could you help me extend it to also disclude links? Here's the [link](https://regex101.com/r/6gpfQX/1)

Comment: As your link demonstrates, the problem is that text _after_ the initial link text (.net) is matching. I don't think there is an easy way to match only text which isn't part of a link without more information about the precise boundary conditions. Programmatically, the easiest is probably to skip links separately, and only then check against the regex above.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just made sure there was whitespace (or start-of-line) in front of the word?

`(?:^|\s)\w*?[aeiou]\w*`

As opposed to testing for something that's always in the emoji, you can test for something that's never in it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHucNr/1/)

Comment: Note that this won't work for, say, quoted sentences or the like, but it answers the question as asked. If you have a more robust set of test cases, please add them to the question and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks for this, and I do need it to work in more cases so I put together a [test set](https://regex101.com/r/DNYUe6/1) which should show all of the cases. Btw, I'm not sure whether this *can* be done in a single regular expression; it seems like it might need variable width lookarounds to work (something the regex implementation I'm working with doesn't support).